# Team Foundation Build Won't Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We had a working build for our solution, but when we added a new project, it stopped working.  The build runs "successfully" and the log shows: *Run MSBuild for Project -> Built [my solution] for target(s) publish* (same for all projects), but it doesn't actually build anything.

The problem seems to be in the build configuration.  My build process definition is set to build for my custom configuration (ForMSBuild | Any CPU), but something is wrong with the way TFB is interpreting that definition (I need that custom configuration because I copy some .dlls to a designated folder to include in a publish process in order to be available for a ClickOnce install).
At one point, only the new .dlls added to the solution weren't building (even though they were listed in the Configuration Manager with the Build check box checked).  So I re-created my custom configuration, ensured that all my .dlls were checked to Build under (ForMSBuild | Any CPU), and now none build.  I have opened the source on the build machine directly in Visual Studio (2012) and verified the settings for my custom configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I actually had the main startup project not checked to build.  Really stupid mistake, but I sure wish MSBuild hadn't spit out all those incorrect messages.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Build Definition, in the Process tab click the ellipsis next to Solutions To Build, go to the Configurations tab and ensure TFS Build is set to build the configuration you want it to:

[image: TFS Build Configurations]

Comment: Yes, checked 1K times.  Ensured I typed in (since you never get anything in the drop list upon clicking Add other than Debug/Release) the correct configuration name.

Comment: Grab the MSBuild log from the TFSBuild and examine what it's doing.  Turn on Verbosity=Diagnostic if need be.

Comment: Verbosity is set to diagnostic; it (incorrectly) reports all projects built.  There are no errors, no warnings.  The only thing I could think to try is manually running the MSBuild command line that TFB runs, changing the parameter /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true to false (thinking there is something wrong with my configuration).  Same result; everything reports built, no errors, no warnings.